# Unrecognized selector in SBJSON with Facebook v3.0.8?

Tags: iphone, facebook, json, sbjson

I downloaded the Facebook SDK 3.0.8, and I am using it as per the instructions (dragging the framework and resource bundles).

I attempt to authenticate, and it works fine.  Then I do:

```
        FBRequest *me = [FBRequest requestForMe];
        [me startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *my,
                                          NSError *error) {

        }];
```

Inside the complettion handler, I do have my user object, so everything worked properly.  (I know this because I NSLog'd out my.id)  However, right after that it gets a unrecognized selector exception with this stacktrace:

```
objc_exception_throw ()
-[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ()
___forwarding___ ()
_CF_forwarding_prep_0 ()
-[SBJSON objectWithString:allowScalar:error:]
-[SBJSON objectWithString:allowScalar:error:]
-[SBJSON objectWithString:error:]
-[FBRequestConnection parseJSONOrOtherwise:error:]
-[FBRequestConnection parseJSONResponse:error:statusCode:]
-[FBRequestConnection completeWithResponse:data:orError:]
__68-[FBRequestConnection startWithCacheIdentity:skipRoundtripIfCached:]_block_invoke_0
-[FBURLConnection invokeHandler:error:response:responseData:]
-[FBURLConnection connectionDidFinishLoading:]
```

This doesn't happen in the simulator, only on my device.  I am on a iPhone4S, running 5.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, really. Please pester Facebook to upgrade their version of SBJson though - the version they use is *ancient*. Upgrading might well fix your issue, if the issue is in the JSON parsing part.

Comment: Yeah, but I am using facebook via their static lib.   Based on other bug reports, I think this is an issue with the new 5.0 facebook app.   If that proves correct, I'll close this question.

Comment: Turns out, this is a conflict with the FacebookSDK version of SBJSON and the version I am using in my app.    I thought using a static lib would prevent that, but I guess not...